# Blogs in Confluence

Tags: confluence

I would like to do the following in confluence:

1. Have one blog per individual (not associated with particular space).
2. Have a set of blogs associated with a space such that anybody who had access to that space could post to them.

Is this possible? How do I do this?

Comment: You might get more responses posting this in serverfault.com.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Set up a Personal Space](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+up+your+Personal+Space) for each individual
2. I'm not sure what you want.

   1. If you want actual multiple blogs in the same space it's impossible, but the solution will be to use one of the following macros (depends on the amount of customization you need):

      1. [Content by Label {contentbylabel}](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Content+by+Label+Macro)
      2. [{blog-list}](http://www.adaptavist.com/display/builder/blog-list+macro)
      3. [{blog-archive}](http://www.adaptavist.com/display/builder/blog-archive+macro)
   2. If you want the personal blogs to be merged into a space blog, I would use the [Content Publishing Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/CCPP/Confluence+Content+Publishing+Plugin) with the {publish-page} macro.
   3. If you just want also a blog per space it's already possible out of the box:
      `You can publish a blog post from any space in Confluence, provided you have permission.` - quoted from [Working with Blog Posts](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Working+with+Blog+Posts)

Answer (score 0):

The only way imho to fulfil your first request is to create personal spaces. There people can start their own blog.
The only way to accumulate those blogs into one space would be to include the pages of a space with the include tag or copy the content of it in the new space with "Content Publishing Plugin" or "Copy Space Plugin" or "Copy Partial Space Plugin", if you don't mind of duplicate entries.